# How to register custom admin for Feincms page module with custom django AdminSite instance

Tags: django, django-admin, feincms

I try to modify feincms `PageAdmin` either by subclassing it or patching it. Neither works when I use custom `AdminSite` instance: MediaLibrary exentsion buttons (they appear after `Page.create_content_type(MediaFileContent...`) disappear when I do so.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from feincms.module.page.modeladmins import PageAdmin
from feincms.module.page.models import Page

paii_admin = admin.AdminSite(name='paii_admin')
paii_admin.index_template = 'admin/cms/index.html'

class SitePageAdmin(PageAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        return super(SitePageAdmin, self).queryset(request)

paii_admin.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

You should register MediaFile (from medialibrary) as well:

```
paii_admin.register(MediaFile, MediaFileAdmin)
```

In `feincms/templates/admin/feincms/_content_type_buttons.html` we have following:

```
{% url "admin:medialibrary_mediafile_changelist" as media_library_url %}
[...]
{% if media_library_url %}
    }, {
        type: 'mediafilecontent',
        keep: true,
        cssclass: 'imagecontent',
        raw_id_picker: '{{ media_library_url }}?type__exact=image&pop=1'
    }, {
        type: 'gallerycontent',
        keep: true
    }, {
        type: 'mediafilecontent',
        keep: true,
        cssclass: 'pdfcontent',
        raw_id_picker: '{{ media_library_url }}?type__exact=pdf&pop=1'
{% endif %}
```

Those fields are populated by JS only if medialibrary is registered to the namespace